# jQuery Event Propagation: fadeIn get call multiple times

Tags: jquery

Here is my base case. If I click on `Text`, a text box will fade in, and put a focus on that text box. When I press Esc, the text box will disappear and the `Text` will fade back in. http://jsfiddle.net/FDjUm/. I have two questions. **Please refer to the below jsfiddle for visual demonstration of my questions**

1) http://jsfiddle.net/FDjUm/4/
I put in an alert box in the `focus`, and it get called infinitely. Why is that and how can I fix it?

2) http://jsfiddle.net/Zh8HR/13/
I put in an alert box in the `fadeIn`. The alert get called multiples times (not infinitely). So I put `return false` then the first time (the first click and press Esc), it work great (alert box only appear 1 time). But the more you click and esc, the more time the alert box appear? Why and how to fix it?

I am new to jQuery, so be criticized if the way I write jQuery is improper. And i want to learn and write good code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alert causes the focus to lose. After clicking ok the focus returns.

Which causes the alert to be displayed which causes the focus to lose. etc etc etc

For number 2

Just move the `keyup` outside th focus function.

Lemme fix that fiddle for you. 1 sec...

http://jsfiddle.net/FDjUm/7/

here you go :)

EDIT

Bit better code:

http://jsfiddle.net/FDjUm/8/

Comment: if I remove the keyup, then when I press Esc, nothing happen. Here is the jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Zh8HR/12/

Comment: @OP: The remove was a typo it should have been move :) I fixed it now.

Comment: @OP: I also changed the code a bit more (see the edit of my answer). I used this as a reference to the element

Comment: work perfect. Thank you. What is the reason that it behave that way when I wrap the keyup around focus()?

Comment: @Harry: everytime the element got the focus the keyup was bind. So basically it binded the keyup several times (1 time for each focus) to the element. Resulting in several messages.

Comment: Thank you very much. In general, when i fade in and fade out like this, do I need to worry about event bubble up to the parent? I know it is crucial to do event.stopPropagation() when deal with click event.

Comment: Don't think you need to worry about propagation on fadeIn fadeOut. The thing with click is if you have a container with a element in it. If you click the 'inner'element you basically also clicking the parent container.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could remove the focus on ESC key:

```
       jQuery("#textBox").blur().hide();
```

I think that you hide the textbox, but the textbox still have the focus...

Answer (score 1):

the fix for the first one (and maybe the second) is to change the line

```
jQuery("#textBox").focus();
```

to use the $.triggerHandler() function :

```
jQuery("#textBox").triggerHandler('focus');
```